# Photo management with video support

Tags: alternative, photography, media-manager, f-spot

F-spot is great, but does not have video support. Picasa is arguably even better, but although mov support is possible, avi and mpeg support is unavailable.

Is there a photo management app that can also work with videos ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DigiKam](http://www.digikam.org/), unfortunately is a KDE app. It will handle videos but its not intended for that purpose. Also you should notice that it might be a bit to much for photo management, but i haven't found an app that can handle photos and videos in an efficient way.

Personally I have given up for now, and I'm using different apps for photos and videos. It's also worth noting that Shotwell is going to have video support, eventually.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really convinced by digiKam... I'm trying Picasa in Wine and Lightroom in virtualbox at the moment, and will choose after trying all three for a while. The simplest would be if f-spot just copied my videos to my computer when I import, though, I don't need anything more than that.

Answer (score 6):

This is included in Shotwell .8, which you can [get here](http://yorba.org/shotwell/).

Comment: Shotwell 0.8 has been released, which includes video support: http://yorba.org/shotwell/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [gwenview [image: Install gwenview]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gwenview), it just may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research, and it looks like [digiKam](http://www.digikam.org) [supports](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-photo-and-video-management-software-811569/) videos and photos. Although a KDE app, I think it's fairly robust and works well even in a GNOME environment.

As some have mentioned, it's UI can be a bit daunting, but once you learn to use it, it can save you a lot of time and hassle in comparison to alternatives. I don't think there are any other apps that support both photos and video at this time on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, at a time when the availability of professional quality photo organizers and video editing software for Linux is still up in the air, I find using a dedicated photo downloader to be a much-needed source of consistency in my photo workflow.

For this I strongly recommend checking out [Rapid Photo Downloader](http://www.damonlynch.net/rapid/). It has powerful options for sorting and renaming photos and videos as they're imported on to the computer, and it can import from multiple memory cards simultaneously while creating backups on the fly.

[image: Rapid Photo Downloader]

Just to be clear, this is a program that is designed to be used side-by-side with your preferred photo organizer. All it does is transfer your photos and videos on to the computer; what you do next with them is up to you.

If you want a more recent version than that in the repositories, you could use the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dlynch3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rapid-photo-downloader
```

Before using any PPAs, please read this:

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)